# Tool to: Locally format (indent and add new lines) xml file

Tags: xml

I have several medium sized (1 MB) xml file that I frequently need to format.  (I am getting them from a program that outputs them with no indentation).

**I am looking for someway to quickly and easily format the files locally on my machine.**

I have been using http://xmlindent.com/ to format them but

- I don't like uploading my content to a third party site
- its a pain in the butt to upload the file, copy it from the page, open a new file paste the results in ...

I know that eclipse has a xml formatter but it is choking because the file size is too big.

My primary editor for xml is vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was to use Notepad++.  Under:

```
Menu: TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy -> Tidy: Reindent XML
```

*Note: This method will only work under Windows Vista & Windows 7 when Notepad++ is being run as admin (right click -> Run as administrator).  When being run as a regular user it will silently fail.*

Answer (score 1):

[XML-Starlet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/files/xmlstarlet/1.3.0) does it on any Unix and even on a Windows Commandline

from the [manual](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s05.html):

```
xml fo your_malformated_file.xml
```

and in vim you just do

```
:%!xml fo
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is simple fixed formatting (newline after each close tag, indent each enclosed tag a fixed number of spaces/tabs), you can probably write a simple program yourself.  You could probably even write a Vim macro to do it.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  I am sure that this must be a common need.

Comment: You also need to deal with things like: Am I in a CDATA section?  Easy on the whole but still a pain in the ass

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude:Just sayin, since it seems the wheels you've found aren't working for you...

Comment: Fair enough.  Found a good (although not stand alone) solution.